# Converting from Unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

How do strip I convert Unicode to strings?

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'A':[u'Joe', u'Bill']})
test = df['A'] == 'Joe'
```

This works on converting columns full to Unicode to floats:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(float)
```

But when I try:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
```

The output is:

```
0    J
1    B
```

Comment: Unicode strings are strings. Are they causing problems for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode is strings, no conversion necessary there.